# UITableViewCell highlight color never goes external link clicked

Tags: ios, select, uitableview, navigation, highlight

I have used grouped UITAbleView for navigation. One of the cell directed to external link which opens safari and app goes to background.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/]]
```

If i open the app again, it shows as table cell still selected. How to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this line in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

`[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

Make the controller clear the selection when table appears. Add the below line of code on load.

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
```